# Checking the AST for @Injectable decorator for TSLint custom rule

Tags: angular, abstract-syntax-tree, tslint

I am trying to design a custom `TSLint` rule that will allow for me to check and make sure that the `@Injectable` decorator is not included within classes that do not inject any other services into themselves via the constructor.

I have been reading [this](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/walker-design.html) documentation and have been able to write a rule previously to disallow `export` modifiers in test files by doing:

```
const hasExport = node.modifiers && node.modifiers.some(
    (modifier) => modifier.kind === SyntaxKind.ExportKeyword
);
```

[This AST explorer website](https://astexplorer.net/) has been helpful throughout this process but I am having trouble deciding the best way to figure out if the `@Injectable` decorator is being added to my node.

So far I have:

```
const hasInjectableDecorator = node.decorators && node.decorators.some(
    (decorator) => decorator.kind === SyntaxKind.Decorator
);
```

But this will only check to see if it is of *any* decorator (@Injectable, @Component, @NgModule, etc.) and I was wondering how I could then check the text, using the available properties/methods on `decorator` to make sure it is indeed an `@Injectable`. I would like to start with this first and then dive into ensuring no other services are being injected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

+1 for astexplorer.net! Great website.

import * as ts from "typescript";

```
const hasInjectableDecorator = (node: ts.ClassDeclaration) => node.decorators
    && node.decorators.some(isInjectableDecorator);

const isInjectableDecorator = (decorator: ts.Decorator) => ts.isIdentifier(decorator.expression)
    && decorator.expression.text === "Injectable"
```

Explanation: you want to check whether the decorator's `expression` has a text value of `"Injectable"`, right? This method will check if the decorator is an Identifier (it refers to a variable), and if so, checks what text name it uses.

Fun fact: instead of checking `node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.Decorator`, you should use the built-in `ts.isDecorator` method *(and its equivalents for other node syntax kinds)*. They directly check `.kind` the same way and also return `node is ts.Decorator`, so you'll get type inference without having to manually cast `node as ts.Decorator` later on.